# ¿Como aplicar unos estilos únicamente para Firefox?

Tags: html5, css3

Estoy haciendo una web donde tengo un acordeón hecho en css3 si bien le apliqué los prefijos propios de cada motor `moz-`, `webkit-`y `o-`  resulta que lo veo en `Firefox` no se me visualiza igual que en `Chrome`.

Quería saber si existen comentarios condicionales para dicho navegador y como se usan. Esta es la web: http://www.berazategui.gov.ar/prueba-portal/

```
        .collapsable2 [type="radio"],
        .collapsable2 [type="checkbox"] {
             background-image: url(../img/flecha.png);
             background-repeat: no-repeat;
            cursor: pointer;
            transform: rotate(0);
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
            background-color: #3c3d3b; 
            background-position: 48% 55%;
            width: 66px;
        }

        .collapsable2 [type="radio"]:hover, .collapsable2 [type="radio"]:focus,
        .collapsable2 [type="checkbox"]:focus {
            background-image: url(../img/flecha2.png);
             background-repeat: no-repeat;
             background-position: 48% 55%;
        }

        .collapsable2 [type="radio"]:checked,
        .collapsable2 [type="checkbox"]:checked {
            background-image: url(../img/flecha.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: 48% 55%;
            transform: rotate(0deg); 
        }

        .collapsable2 [type="radio"]:checked + div,
        .collapsable2 [type="checkbox"]:checked + div {
              max-height: 496px; 
               background-image: url(../img/texture.png);
        }

        .collapsable2 [type="radio"] + div,
        .collapsable2 [type="checkbox"] + div {
              flex: 0 0 100%;
              height: auto;
              overflow: hidden;
              max-height: 0;
              -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
              -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
              -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
              transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
        }
```

Comment: ¿quieres que tampoco se vea en Firefox? Comparte tu código por favor.

Comment: http://www.berazategui.gov.ar/prueba-portal/

Comment: Se aplica en el mismo css? porque probé y nada.

Comment: @MarianoAndrésFranco por favor, comparte en esta página un **trozo** de tu código en el que se pueda reproducir el problema para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: ahi edite la pregunta y agregue el código.

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es que unos determinados CSS se apliquen únicamente a Firefox podrías usar lo siguiente:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
   //Dentro irían todos los estilos que quieres que se apliquen solo en Firefox.
}
```

De esta manera, podrás aplicar los estilos para Chrome como harías normalmente y los estilos "especiales" para Firefox dentro del filtro anterior.

Comment: Hola francisco gracias! estoy probando pero nada che! como que no me los reconoce.

Comment: @MarianoAndrésFranco ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de que es lo que no te está cogiendo?

Comment: si el problema que tengo son con los acordeones que estan a la derecha cuando los visualizo en mozilla